# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS black screen after suspension on Dell Inspiron 15

Tags: graphics, 16.04, suspend

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my new laptop from Dell with both an integrated graphics card Intel HD graphics 520 and a dedicated graphics card AMD radeon r5 m335. In my system settings/details, only the integrated intel HD 520 card is listed. When I close the lid, it is supposed to go to suspension mode. But the fan keeps running and the machine gets hot. When I open the lid again, it's just a black screen. I have to hard reboot to get it back.

I also have windows 10 on it. It had the same issue of black screen. I solved that by installing AMD display driver updates.

Any help in resolving this issue is deeply appreciated because it is so frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it's a very new laptop. Maybe it's not fully supported just yet. You could try one of the mainline kernels, with better AMD support by amdgpu. Get the files from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/

download linux-headers-4.6.0-040600_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_all.deb, linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_amd64.deb, linux-headers-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_amd64.deb.

go into the folder (make sure you don't have any other files beginning with linux in there, open terminal in that folder and:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux*
```

reboot.

I'm not really sure how good the dual GPU is with AMD and Linux though. That you will have to figure out from googling.

Comment: You are welcome :) Glad it worked out!

Comment: That did solve the black screen problem. However, I had other problems popping up. Like battery won't charge when plugged in. So I decided to downgrade to 15.10. There was still the black screen problem and your solution still worked. Hoping that no other problems will pop up this time.

Comment: Just to follow up, it turned out to cause other issues with other software. I was trying to use virtualbox and it said that the specific files listed above were not supported. Now I am left with no viable choice. Will try to install ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Tried ubuntu 14.04 and that still did not work. Eventually I got tired and just decided to update the system to the latest (16.04 LTS) and deal with it. To my delight, everything started to work after the update. I am not sure why though.